# Download android source code to external directory

Tags: java, android, ubuntu

I am using **ubuntu** 11.10 I have initialized repo and start downloading source code *for build my own rom* but now my dir is full so I cant resume downloading for another source code,Please suggest me how can I move this data to my external hard drive

Answer (score 0):

When you install the SDK Bundle, simply install it to your external drive.  It is not recommended to run the SDK off an external drive (you might see performance issues).

If you are trying to save space on your current install, just don't install very many Platform Versions (ie, the SDK for Gingerbread and ICS - just use 1 version).

Furthermore, the source code takes up a lot of space, if you aren't using it (to debug directly into source code via your IDE for instance) - you may not want to download that either.

Bottom line, I wouldn't try to run the SDK from an external drive, and instead, be selective on which components your download and install to save space.

The APIs and source code are installed in this dir, if you want to look around (you could copy the source out of here to your external drive to actually answer you initial question):

```
 ${ANDROID_HOME}/android/sdk/platforms
```

Comment: I have edited my answer,I want to create ROM thats why I am downloading source code not sdk